# UIScrollView works like UITableView

Tags: ios

I want to use UIScrollView instead of UITableView but i should contains the dequeue feature same as TableView. Is there any tutorial or sample project by which i get help to make a UIScrollView functioning like UITableView.

Comment: It depends on what you want to put into your scroll view.  (Note that `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, which makes the point that dequeue is a function of what the scroll view contains.)

Comment: instead you can use customTableViewCell and headers and footers view to attain your design requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no there is no dequeueing function on the scroll view, that is what a table view is for!

So my question to you is: what is it what you're trying to do and I can maybe help you out.

Comment: I want to design a view which has Rows and Columns. And this view should scroll horizontally for Columns and vertically for Row. I have try this with UIScrollView but Data is so much to load that app is giving memory warning on scrolling and at one time it become crash. So i want to use Deqeueing functionality of TableView in ScrollView.